# React.js error "this.state.product.response.map is not a function"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, reactjs

I am a very newbie learning React.js and building a CRUD application using Visual Studio 2017 using MVC framework and Entity framework. I have found myself in a hole and stuck there for ages trying to retrieve data from a Product table in MSSQL through ajax calls to the Index method in the controller and then render it on the browser.

I have a Product Table and a Product class :

```
public partial class Product
{


    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

Product Controller code is:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller

{
  private SalesModel db = new SalesModel();
    // GET: Product

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Products.ToList());
    }
}
```

The Product.jsx is:

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        product: {
            Id: 1,
            ProductName: "Microwave",
            Price: 120.90,
            response: []
        }
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("/Products/Index").then(response => {
        //console.log(response.data);  
        this.setState({
            product: Object.assign({}, this.state.product, { response: response.data })
        });
    });
}

render() {

    return (
        <section>
            <h1>Products List</h1>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead><tr><th>Product Id</th><th>Product Name</th> 
      <th>Product Price</th></tr></thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {
                            this.state.product.response.map((item, key) => {
                                return <tr key={key}><td>{item.Id}</td><td> 
 {item.ProductName}</td><td>{item.Price}</td></tr>;
                        })
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>


        </section>
    )
}
```

}

```
ReactDOM.render(<ProductsList/>,document.getElementById('myContainer'));
```

View is:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@model IEnumerable<MarsOnBoardTasks.ViewModels.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<html>

<body>
<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="myContainer" class="container">

</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel- 
core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
@* Jquery *@
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
@* React Library *@
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react- 
dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

@* ReactJS components *@
@*<script src="/Scripts/Product.jsx"></script>*@
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/React/Product.jsx")
```

Comment: You are making an ajax call (to be used in react state) to an action method which returns a view result (HTML) ? Why ?

Comment: what does that commented out console log, log?

Comment: Hi Shyju, If I get you correctly,  the ajax call response from the controller method needs to be used by React as front end for rendering in the browser. I am not sure how else can I retrieve the Products from database through MVC framework. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi azium, it logs: Object
Id
:
1
Price
:
120.9
ProductName
:
"Microwave"
response
:
Array(0)
length
:
0

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your response is an array.
.maps only work for array, not object
Use Object.entries().it will make the key & value of object into array,

```
{"a":1} => [0]="a",[1]=1

Object.entries(this.state.product).map((product)=>{})
```

Comment: Vynart, I know that . Can you tell me what works for object or in other words how do you handle objects returned from database?

Comment: thanks and the error no more appears with your code and the original issue is sorted. I now run into another problem which is that the response object doesn't show the database object. Any suggestion as to how to get the table records will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

please Read more about `Life cycle` in Reactjs.

`componentDidMount` run after `render(){` function.
when use `this.state.product.response.map` state not set and It's empty.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Ok then what should I do to get the response object populated in Reactjs. A suitable reply is what I am after to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is now all sorted out. As @Shyju  rightly pointed out, I was pointing to the wrong action method which was returning a view where I needed to get a Jason object array as response. I have now correctly pointed out to the method that returns Json and everything is sorted. Thanks to all who tried to help

Comment: @shyju Response from you ultimately led to the solution